# Qual a opção mais simples para hospedar arquivo texto em nuvem e ler e gravar seu conteúdo, programaticamente, com javascript - (Não é Download)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extensão, google-drive-api

Olá, tenho uma extensão que quero manter salvo apenas um arquivo texto de configurações para cada usuário. De início, saliento que opções de armazenamento temporário ou pouco persistentes como *localStorage*, *sessionStorage* e até o *indexedDB*, não servem, simplesmente porque elas usam a política de mesmo domínio. Por isso pensei em armazenamento de tal(is) arquivos em nuvem, mas a opção de um grande serviço como o Google Drive, me pareceu/parece bem complicada para usar a API deles, fuçei bastante e não entendi ou cansei sem entender como acessar o texto de um arquivo que esteja lá (no Google Drive), internamente na extensão (ou página HTML, que seja), com javascript. Eu quero apenas guardar esse arquivo, recuperar na página HTML seu conteúdo, editar e salvar as alterações (lá no Google Drive, novamente). PS: me referi ao Google Drive, mas pode ser qualquer serviço *Cloud* que seja de simples acesso para a minha necessidade. Inclusive, pesquisei alguns serviços de armazenamento em nuvem que disponibilizam um *link* para baixar o arquivo via *download*, mas o que preciso é a possibilidade de ler internamente com Javascript para manipular seu conteúdo.

Tentei esse código abaixo - um entre dezenas que consultei, mas que não funcionou. Existem muitas atualizações no histórico de informações sobre acesso de tipo de API.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Javascript - Api Fetch</title>
</head>
<body>
    Teste da API Fetch
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    <script>
    function start() {
      // 2. Initialize the JavaScript client library.
      gapi.client.init({
        'apiKey': 'myAPIKey',
        // clientId and scope are optional if auth is not required.
        //'clientId': 'YOUR_WEB_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        //'scope': 'profile',
      }).then(function() {
        // 3. Initialize and make the API request.
        return gapi.client.request({
          'path': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
        })
      }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.result);
      }, function(reason) {
        console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
      });
    };
    // 1. Load the JavaScript client library.
    gapi.load('client', start);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Queira [edit] e converter o problema em um [mcve], que a pergunta vai para reavaliação. Seguem links que podem ajudar a participar de maneira eficaz e útil para o coletivo: [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help)
- [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256)
- [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089)
- [Guia rápido sobre como fazer perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [Assuntos e tipos de perguntas permitidos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: A conversa ficou extensa e foi [movda para uma sala de bate-papo](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148508/discussion-on-question-by-fernandes-qual-a-opcao-mais-simples-para-hospedar-arqu);